# What is the differences between the a Data or File transfer and send?

Tags: solidity

Well, i have transferred some data and files from an opposite manufacturer android using the Smartwatch app? So, I am worried about if the same amount of data least has left on the opposite android or what exactly the impact would be on such operations please? Also, want to be cleared if what would have been the differences between if I have had this by sending or as of I did transferred it?
I had chosen my opposite android as my old device and mine one as if my new one, so if?
Thank you so much.

```
e2255nter code13 here8e
```

Comment: I think you are on the wrong stack exchange lol